# How to use Get-ChildItem with Regex in one command

Tags: powershell

I've this command in PowerShell following :

```
Get-ChildItem  –File  -Name
```

I've this kind of result :

```
50050100014_preview.png
50050100014_thumbnail.png
50050100016_master.png
50050100016_preview.png
50050100016_thumbnail.png
50050100017_master.png
50050100017_preview.png
50050100017_thumbnail.png
```

I would like to apply this regex `"_[a-zA-Z]+.png"` for have just the number in the names of files. How to join the Regex in one line of command.

Comment: For the file 50050100014_preview.png, only output 50050100014?

Comment: @ReddyLutonadio Get-ChildItem will query files. OP wants to filter a folder with lots of files based on a regex and only return that resultset, not all files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will simply need to replace anything in the string that matches the regex. you can use the `-replace` operator for that.

```
(Get-ChildItem -File -Name) -replace '_[a-zA-Z]+.png'
```

Example output:

```
PS C:\xy> Get-ChildItem -File -Name
50050100014_preview.png
50050100014_thumbnail.png
50050100016_master.png

PS C:\xy> (Get-ChildItem -File -Name) -replace '_[a-zA-Z]+.png'
50050100014
50050100014
50050100016
```